# javaScript funky cookie?

Tags: javascript

When I try to read my cookie that I have set something does not seem right

Here is my cookie functions

```
function readCookie(){
if (document.cookie !=""){
    document.getElementsByName("eMail").innerHTML = alert("hello, " +    
document.cookie.split("=")[1]);
}
}

//for setting cookies
function writeCookie(cName, cValue, expDate, cPath, cDomain, cSecure){
if(cName && cValue!= ""){
var cString = cName + " = " + escape(cValue);

if (expDate) cString += ";expires=" + expDate,toGMString();
if (cPath) cString += ";path=" + cPath;
if (cDomain) cString += ";domain=" + cDomain;
if (cSecure) cString += ";secure";

document.cookie = cString;
}
}
```

cookie being set

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"     
onclick="writeCookie('userId',document.getElementsByName('eMail').value)"/>
```

alert box

```
hello, undefined;__utma
```

thought on what this means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alert function returns `undefined`

So

```
 document.getElementsByName("eMail").innerHTML = alert("hello, " + 
       document.cookie.split("=")[1]);
```

Is setting the html of `eMail` to `undefined`.

Also, `getElementsByName` returns a *collection* of elements.

Did you mean

```
document.getElementsByName("eMail")[0].innerHTML = "hello, " +    
       document.cookie.split("=")[1];
```

Or are there multiple elements with this name?

```
var eMailElements = document.getElementsByName("eMail");
for (var i = 0; i < eMailElements.length; i++)
    eMailElements[i].innerHTML = "hello, " + document.cookie.split("=")[1];
```

Finally, if there's only **one** element you're targeting, you can give it a (unique) **id**, then simply do

```
document.getElementById("eMailId").innerHTML = "hello, " +    
       document.cookie.split("=")[1];
```

Comment: document.getElementsByName was the culprit I switched it to ID and it wors though it is still giving me the  __UTMA at the end of alert string

Comment: @Overcranked - I'm really not sure.  I would gather up all your updated code, and post a new question with the error message.

Answer (score 3):

A few problems:

```
if(cName && cValue!= ""){
```

Change it to this:

```
if ((cName != "") && (cValue != "")) {
```

Also this line has a problem:

```
if (expDate) cString += ";expires=" + expDate,toGMString();
                                             ^ Should be a period
```

Answer (score 0):

I see `__utma` in there which tells me one thing: You have Google ads somewhere on the page. They set cookies for tracking users, and your script is reading them. Your method of reading cookies is wrong anyway.

```
function readCookie(cName) {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";"),
        l = cookies.length, i, k, v;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        v = cookies[i].split("=");
        k = v.shift();
        v = v.join("=");
        if( k == cName) return v;
    }
}
```

Also, `getElementsByName()` returns a NodeList, so you need to get `[0]` off of it, or use `getElementById()` instead when writing the cookie - this is why the cookie result is undefined.

Comment: Google Analytics? Any other Google-hosted code? jQuery perhaps? Anyway, the main point is that this will make it easier if you ever have more cookies than just one.